# Inserting row types with a serial primary key column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, insert, primary-key, default, rowtype

I want a simple function that takes in all record columns and creates them if it does not exist. The table here is just a dummy, my point is more about how the id (SERIAL) column must be handled when inserting data using row types.

```
CREATE TABLE
  some_table (
    "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "some_value" VARCHAR NOT NULL
  );
```

```
declare
    r_some_table_rt some_table%rowtype;
begin
    select *
    into r_some_table_rt
    from some_table
    where some_column = 'Some value';

  if r_some_table_rt.id is null then
    -- Tried without assigning r_some_table_rt.id
    -- r_some_table_rt.id := default; -- Tried this
    -- r_some_table_rt.id := currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('some_table', 'id')); -- And this
    r_some_table_rt.some_column := 'Some other value';

    insert into some_table
    values (r_some_table_rt.*)
    returning id into r_some_table_rt.id;

  end if;

  return r_some_table_rt.id;
end;
```

`PostgresError: null value in column "id" of relation "some_table" violates not-null constraint`

I tried the following

1. Using a normal insert works perfectly fine: `insert into some_table (some_column) values ('Some value');`.
2. `r_some_table.id := default;` -> `PostgresError: DEFAULT is not allowed in this context`
3. `r_some_table.id := currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('some_table', 'id'));` -> `PostgresError: currval of sequence "some_table_id_seq" is not yet defined in this session`

Comment: If you want to duplicate a row, then why not use an INSERT .. SELECT?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added some explanation for completeness' sake.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`r_some_table_rt.id := nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('some_table', 'id'));`